# How do I specify multiple sort key columns?

Tags: amazon-redshift

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115069/what-does-it-mean-to-have-multiple-sortkey-columns) indicates that you can have multiple sort key columns. However, I can not figure out the correct syntax. This works fine for one column:

```
create table elt.tmptmp (
  val1 smallint sortkey,
  val2 smallint,
);
```

This is how I'd assume it would work for multiple columns, but it results in an error:

```
create table elt.tmptmp (
  val1 smallint,
  val2 smallint,
  sortkey(val1, val2)
);

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

How do I specify a sort key on multiple columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table tablename (...) sortkey (..., ...);
```

in your case, this should work:

```
create table elt.tmptmp (
  val1 smallint,
  val2 smallint,
)  
sortkey(val1, val2);
```

as in [Create Table - Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_examples.html).

Comment: Ah thanks, I had assumed it would work the same as assigning constraints.